# Add additional managers to Company Page

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, jobs, company

Is it possible to add additional SO users as managers or admins for a company page? I created our company page myself on a weekend, but I'd like to let someone else at the company polish it up a bit without giving them my login. I don't see an obvious way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you use your account to create the company page or a separate one?

Comment: I like this idea as well. This would be a great feature for where I work as well.

Comment: @RyanGates, I just used my own account (the one I'm using now.)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create a company account and then share that one among multiple people?

Answer (score 2):

Update: Any user who is an admin on the company account can edit the company page (not just the owner).

---

Quick answer is no.  Currently you can only have a single user own and edit a company page.  Company pages are no different from job listings in this regard.

The good news is we just started work on Company Accounts which will allow multiple users within a company/organization to exchange products (job listings, company pages, search subscriptions). Additionally users within the same company will be able to attribute editing rights to others if they are the primary owner of a product (only relevant for job listings and company pages).

It's a pretty major feature that will be released in multiple iterations, but it is well underway and coming soon.